# How do you organize this query by week

Tags: postgresql

Here is my Query so far:

```
select one.week, total, comeback, round(comeback)::Numeric / total::numeric  * 100  as comeback_percent
FROM
    (
        SELECT count(username) as total, week
        FROM
            (
            select row_number () over (partition by u.id order by creation_date) as row, username, date_trunc ('month', creation_date)::date AS week
            FROM users u
            left join entries e on u.id = e.user_id
            where ((entry_type = 0 and distance >= 1) or (entry_type = 1 and seconds_running >= 600))
            ) x
        where row = 1
        group by week
        order by week asc
    ) one

join

    (
        SELECT count(username) as comeback, week
        FROM
            (
            select row_number () over (partition by u.id order by creation_date) as row, username, runs_completed, date_trunc ('month', creation_date)::date AS week
            FROM entries e
            left join users u on e.user_id = u.id
            where ((entry_type = 0 and distance >= 1) or (entry_type = 1 and seconds_running >= 600))
            ) y
        where runs_completed > 1 and row = 1
        group by week
        order by week asc
    ) two 

on one.week = two.week
```

What I want to accomplish, is return a line graph for users that have completed one run with us, grouped by week, and assign percentages for that week of anyone who has completed a second run EVER, not just within that week. Our funnel has improved by a factor of 5 since we started, yet the line graph that is produced does not show similar results.

I could be incorrectly joining them together, or there may be a cleaner way to use CTE or window functions to perform this query, I am open to any and all suggestions. Thanks!

If you need tables or further information, let me know. I'm happy to provide anything that may be needed.